# How to get the files only from a bzr repository?

Tags: version-control, bazaar

I meant, I don't need all the ".bzr" folders under each directory (I may have hundreds of nested ".bzr" folders); I want to check out those actual files only. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really sure you have hundreds of nested ".bzr" folders? There should be only ONE `.bzr` folder per project, right at the top level directory of the project, no additional `.bzr` folders in subdirectories. (You might be mixing it up with Subversion?)

It seems that maybe you want to get all the project files without any `.bzr` folders or Bazaar files. If that's the case, `cd` to your project and run any of these commands:

```
bzr export /tmp/project-as-dir  # export files into a directory
bzr export /tmp/project.tar     # export files into a tar file
bzr export /tmp/project.tar.gz  # export files into a tar.gz file
```

Comment: Yes, I mixedem up with subversion..., and bzr export is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the folders, e.g. using `find -type d -name .bzr -exec rm -rf {} +`

Note that you won't be able to use bzr in that copy anymore (i.e. you can't commit stuff etc.).